# Stupid audits (yes, again)

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Could someone explain why [this is not a valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1627396)? If the OP felt this was the answer to his question, then it is. If there isn't any other solution, this is the answer he was looking for. I'm getting really, really sick of these audits.

[Other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166438/incorrect-audits) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167956/stupid-audits-again) [about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165694/reopen-question-review-audit-fail-clarification) [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165694/reopen-question-review-audit-fail-clarification/165696#165696) [stupid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stupid) [audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167962/how-many-failed-audits-to-be-put-on-quarantine).

Comment: Why is the word stupid not a link? Is it too stupid?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn You don't need a link for that. It refers to this very post.

Comment: People really love to downvote.

Comment: @Emil [downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), people just disagree.

Answer (score 21):

I disagree.

While it's true that it's a self-answer by the OP, it's absolutely not an answer- it's clearly meant as additional information, the kind of information that would fit well in a comment or an edit to the original post.

Imagine that you Googled this issue, and came across this question, happy to see that it has answers. Would you be satisfied by the answer that it occurs only in certain operating systems?

Comment: I don't think that it is clearly meant to add additional information, but I agree it _could_. The poster is an old user and clearly knows the SO system to some extent, and I doubt he would have used the Answer-button for a non-answer. The question isn't a good question, so I wouldn't expect an answer to be that very informative.

Comment: @Emil "I doubt he would have used the Answer-button for a non-answer"  Well, that's *exactly* what he did, so it seems there is no doubt to be had.  What he *might* do is not something we need to theorize about; he very clearly *did* do it.  That answer is just trying to clarify the question, not answer it.  He's describing how to reproduce the problem, not how to fix it.

Comment: @Emil: `The poster is an old user and clearly knows the SO system to some extent`- while the OP has asked 17 questions on StackOverflow, he has only edited any of those questions [once](http://stackoverflow.com/users/599987/bernhard?tab=activity), back in August 2011. This is probably an indication he's not too familiar with the practice.

Comment: @Emil - While they intended this as an answer, it really wasn't a solution to the problem. It was additional information that fit better as a comment. That's why, when this was flagged as not being an answer, I converted it to a comment on the question. However, I understand that this might not have been the clearest item in an audit, which is why I support [moderators being able to label what non-answers should and should not be used for audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168374/bring-a-human-factor-into-review-audit-composition-selection).

Answer (score 10):

It's not an answer because the OP isn't answering any question, just adding conflicting information from what was in the question. The question states:

> "It happens in all browsers and operating systems"

Then the answer is:

> "There is no problem when using Windows or OSX"

So is that an answer? No... that just means the information in the question was incorrect. The actual question from the post was:

> "When I click like the site is liked but when I add a personalized message to the share nothing appears on my wall....Does anyone know why this is happening?"

So

> "I have found out that the problem only occurs in Linux."

Does not even attempt to answer the question. That's why it's not a valid answer.
I have to disagree with your sentiment `If the OP felt this was the answer to his question, then it is.`
If the OP is happy with the fact that his problem only happens in Linux, then he can remove his question, but that won't help anyone else who wants to understand *why* the problem is happening, or wants to fix it.