# Can we please see the subject of failed review audits even if the post has been deleted in the meantime?

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, review-audits

Yesterday I encountered (and failed) a [low quality review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/1560384).

I re-read the post, found that I disagreed with the audit result and clicked <kbd>I Understand</kbd> to continue reviewing. I opened the review today, to take a second look but the page just tells me "answer not found".

Whether there was an audit or not - I like to go over my reviews again some time later and see what others made of them (especially in the suggested-edits queue) or if I see them differently by then. For audits based on deleted posts that is not possible.

So here's the feature request: Please show the subject of review audits as it has been displayed when audited, even if the post in question has by now been deleted.

NB: This topic came up now, because yesterday I disagreed with said audit - and would very much like to take a second look at the post again, to see if I still disagree or whether I now (with a good night's sleep in between) agree...

Comment: Not related to your feature request, but that post was 'bad' because it was just a spam post; It did not answer the actual question asked at all, and included non-disclosed links to the user's website. It was flagged three times as spam, it looks like.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks for clarifying. I read the post, found a text regarding unit tests in a certain context, backed up by some links. The question title said something about unit testing in PHP, so the answer looked valid to me (not a link only, not obvious spam). I didn't click the links to find out if the post author had anything to do with them, so I assume this is an edge case one could discuss. Which has [happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160784/failed-low-quality-review-audit) [before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166438/incorrect-audits) (the discussion...)

Comment: It's not really an edge case so much as it's an extremely prolific spammer. He has gotten good at posting 'junk text' in his answers; often meaningless or random, almost never related to the post he's answering. He creates multiple accounts, and even posts his own questions to have an excuse to link to his site again. Oh... he also submits edits where he tries to inject his links into other peoples' posts.

Comment: @AndrewBarber This information (multiple accounts, creates questions himself to provide spam answers) is not available to a standard LQ-reviewer. All the reviewer can see is the content of the post. And this is what the reviewer can use to judge the posts quality. Nothing more, nothing less. In this case the content was a text that seemed to be related to the questions topic, supported by two links. And without further information this is by no means low quality in my opinion. (But as I said: It *could* be discussed whether this post is an adequate audit, question is, whether it *should*...)

Comment: Isn't the question's content shown, too? That's really all I needed to see: Not on the right topic, really, and contained links.

Comment: @AndrewBarber that's why I wanted to look a second time at the post and thus made this feature request: because obviously I *was* wrong here, but I would like to see the post in its full beauty again on the review page...

Comment: @Spontifius D'uh, of course; makes sense to me now! (I'm dense, sometimes!)